# EF Codefirst - table mapping using fluent api

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have following class:

```
public class User
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }       
    //keys       
    public ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
}
public class Conversation
{        
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public User RecipientUser { get; set; }
    public User SenderUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using EntityTypeConfiguration using fluent Api which are:

```
public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Conversations).WithRequired(x => x.RecipientUser);
    }
}
public class ConversationConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Conversation>
{
    public ConversationConfig()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        HasRequired(x => x.RecipientUser).WithMany(x => x.Conversations);                   
    }
}
```

this is a simple  chat application program. if I am currentUser than I am the sender of message. Recipient user is the one i am sending my message to. 
Please suggest how i configure my EntityTypeConfiguration. I am getting errors like: **Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Conversation_RecipientUser_Target' of the relationship 'DataAcessLayer.Conversation_RecipientUser' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my `Conversation` class as follows:

```
public class Conversation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SenderUserID { get; set; }
    public User SenderUser { get; set;}
    public int RecipientUserID { get; set; }
    public User RecipientUser { get; set; }
}
```

and removed my `UserConfig` fluent api. Instead I added mapping in my `ConversationConfig.cs` file as:

```
public class ConversationConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Conversation>
{
   public ConversationConfig()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.ID);
        HasRequired(c => c.SenderUser).WithMany(u => u.Conversations)
                          .HasForeignKey(c => c.SenderUserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        HasRequired(c => c.RecipientUser).WithMany()
                          .HasForeignKey(c => c.RecipientUserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);          
    }
}
```

(One of the foreign keys doesn't have cascaded delete because that will cause a SQL-Server error: multiple cascade paths).
And It's worked. 
Thanks for your helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part

```
HasRequired(x => x.RecipientUser).WithMany(x => x.Conversations);
```

from ConversationConfig

Comment: I tried your code on my machine and I just removed the part HasRequired(x => x.RecipientUser).WithMany(x => x.Conversations) because this is doing the same thing in your UserConfig, HasMany(x => x.Conversations).WithRequired(x => x.RecipientUser). You should only declare it once.